# Перезаписать файл, разнеся каждое предложение на новую строку, пользуясь только функциями обработки строк

Tags: c, файлы

Язык си.
Есть текстовый файл с предложениями. Необходимо осуществить запись этих предложений в другой файл с условием того,что каждое предложение должно быть на своей строке. Нельзя использовать посимвольную обработку и динамическое выделение памяти. Только использовать функции обработки строк в си

```
        #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <iostream>
        int main()

        {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        const char fn[40] = "input.txt";
        const char fn2[40] = "output.txt";
        char str[500];
        char* pp;
        FILE* f;
        FILE* f2;
        //открыть файл
        if ((f = fopen(fn, "rb")) == NULL)      //при ошибке вывести сообщение
        {
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла %s\n", fn);
        getchar();
        return 0;       //и выйти из функции
        }
        if ((f2 = fopen(fn2, "w")) == NULL)     //при ошибке вывести сообщение
        {
        printf("Ошибка открытия файла %s\n", fn);
        getchar();
        return 0;       //и выйти из функции
        }
        while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), f) != NULL)
        {

        if ((pp = strchr(str, '.')) || (pp = strchr(str, '!')) || (pp = 
        strchr(str, '?')))
            *pp = '\n';
        fputs(str, f2);
        }
        fclose(f2);
        getchar();
        return 0;
        }
```

Предложения переносятся на новые строки, но не все. По моей задумке знаки концов предложений должны замениться на '\n', пробовала strstr, strtok,strrchr. Переносятся в основном первое, второе предложение. остальные остаются слепленными. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ага, так мы и стали за вас домашку делать. Лучше покажите код, который у вас уже есть, и скажите, что конкретно не работает или не получилось.

Comment: все,что на данный момент существует - прикреплено теперь, добавила

Answer (score 0):

```
        while((pp = strchr(str, '.')) || (pp = strchr(str, '!')) || (pp = strchr(str, 
        '?')))
```

заменить if на while и все будет получше)